# Array: how to shfit an element to the top

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
$arr = [
     "A" => "a",
     "B" => "b",
     "C" => "c",
     "D" => "d"
]
```

My desire output is

```
$out = [
     "C" => "c",
     "A" => "a",
     "B" => "b",
     "D" => "d"
]
```

how to apply it? take "c" out then unshift it?

Comment: you already got the operative word: _unshift_

Comment: but array_unshift will give back array with duplicate "C" => "c",my problem is i dont know how to take "c" out by value, not by key@Ghost

Comment: either use array unique or unset it

Comment: @Sherif hhh I agree

Comment: @Sherif If you look at the link, the answer is not array_unshift.